# IcedTea java was blocked because it is out of date

Tags: google-chrome, icedtea

IcedTea is not working and whenever I click "update" it just takes me to a wiki page about IcedTea. I am new to ubuntu and Linux in general so this is very frustrating for me. I need to get this fixed to be able to do my chemistry homework online. Please help me! 
(I have looked at other questions similar to this but I do not understand their answers. I have even tried some of the suggestions without success)

I have seen many people say that this is a bug but I do not know how to fix bugs or how to implement fixes. please help 
thank you

Comment: If it's a bug then it should be added as a bug on launchpad, so the developers can fix it. All bug report questions will be closed here on AU because they are considered off topic, check the FAQ. see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/5121/10698) on how to report a bug.

Comment: In additional to looking at [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) as Alvar suggested, I also recommend carefully reading [the community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Comment: But I do not know if it is a bug or not. I have seen people say that they had a similar problem and others commented saying it was a bug. One person even said that the bug was already fixed :\

Answer (score 2):

Er actually you should simply launch a terminal and type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to update the IcedTea plugin.

Comment: That did not help. I think I already tried that. I do not know what is wrong :[ but I think it is more than what it seems